# No output produce after running the code. Blank and got nothing. Why?

Tags: c, strcpy

No output produce after running the code. Blank and got nothing. What is the problem ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* foo(){
    char temp[] = "World";
    char *result;
    strcpy(result, temp);
    return result;
}

int main(){
    printf("%s", foo());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't allocate memory for `result`.

Comment: `char *result = malloc(strlen(temp)+1);`

Comment: @mnistic. Juts to add may favorite nitpick: The variable `result` *has* memory allocated to it. Exactly 8 bytes if we assume a 64 bit pointers. What has *not* been allocated is an array to hold the copied string that `result` is supposed to point at.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `result` hasn't been assigned any memory here. So, You first need to allocate some memory to it, otherwise, you would be getting a segmentation fault.

One way of doing this would be allocating the memory dynamically, by using `calloc` or `malloc` here. It is found in `stdlib.h` header file. So, you have to include that. Then,

```
char *result = malloc(strlen(temp)+1);
```

would do the trick.

Comment: "*otherwise, you would be getting a segmentation fault.*" - using uninitialized pointer would lead to undefined behavior. Segmentation fault is only one of the possibilities but anything can happen, including the case when `World` will be printed as expected.

Comment: You should probably mention memory leaks and freeing allocated memory and capturing the result of the function.

Comment: Just to add some explanation for someone who is not familiar with `malloc`: the memory allocated with `malloc` is not stored in `result`, it is not part of the variable `result`, neither does it belong to it. `result` is just a pointer, it tells us where the newly allocated memory is, so we can find it when we need it. The allocated memory block  exist totally independent of any pointers pointing at it.